# Proving sequence of expectation converges

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}, \ldots$ be a sequence of random variables on a probability space with the property that $E(X_{n}^{2}) \leq c$ for some constant $c$. Given that $X_{n}$ converges almost surely to $X$, show that $E(X)$ is finite, and also show that $E(X_n)$ converges to $E(X)$.

This is a book problem that I was given as a practice for my upcoming probability exam. But I am unable to solve it, and I would like to study for my exam, so I am hoping someone can help explain the solution to me. This chapter covers mostly inequalities. There are many inequalities covered (if anyone would like, I can list them), and I think that I need to use some combination of these inequalities to prove this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$EX^{2} \leq \lim inf EX_n^{2}$ by Fatou's Lemma so $X$ has finite second moment, hence also finite first moment. We can now reduce the proof to the case when $X=0$ by replacing $X_n$ by $X_n-X$.

$EX_n=EY_n+EZ_n$ where $Y_n=X_nI_{|X_n| \leq M}$ and $Z_n=X_nI_{|X_n| > M}$. For any fixed value of $M$ it is clear that $EY_n \to 0$ by bounded convergence theorem.

Now consider $EZ_n$. By C-S/Holder's inequality $E|Z_n| \leq \sqrt {EX_n^{2}} \sqrt {EI_{|X_n| > M}}=\sqrt {EX_n^{2}} \sqrt {P(|X_n| >M)}$. Finally use Chebyshev's inequality to get $P(|X_n| >M) \leq \frac 1 {M^{2}} EX_n^{2}$.

Given $\epsilon >0$ choose $M$ so large that $\frac c {M^{2}}<(\frac {\epsilon} {2 \sqrt c})^{2}$. Then we get $EZ_n <\epsilon /2$. Now, for this fixed $M$ we c an choose $n_0$ such that $EY_n <\epsilon /2$ for $n \geq n_0$. Hence $EX_n <\epsilon$ for all $n \geq n_0$.

Comment: I understand everything written so far. This shows $E|Z_{n}| \leq E|X_{n}^{2}|/M$. But how does this show $Z_{n}$ goes to $0$?

Comment: I see we are supposed to choose $M < \epsilon$. How does that show convergence though?

Comment: Choose $M$ large to make the probability small.

Comment: @georoberto55 I have given a detailed proof now.